# JSF navigating to a different view programatically

Tags: jsf, facelets

My application has a save and retrieve function. I have the save/retrieve working in that the objects are saved to a database and retrieved correctly. However, in my retrieve landing page, depending on the state of the saved application, I either want to validate some details with the user, or silently navigate to the last accessed view. The latter is where I'm having trouble.

We're using spring beans and in my SaveAndRetrieve page bean I have:

```
  @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        caseNotFound = false;
        caseReference = saveAndRetrieveActionHandler.getRequestedCaseReference();
        LOGGER.debug("Retrieve initialise. Case ref is {}", caseReference);
        if (caseReference != null) {

            try {
                saveAndRetrieveActionHandler.retrieveApplicationByCaseRef();
                LOGGER.debug("Retrieve initialise - case found");

                final NavigationOutcome outcome = saveAndRetrieveActionHandler.getLastAccessedView();
                if (outcome.getApplicationState() == ApplicationState.QUOTE) {
                    LOGGER.info("Quote retrieved, navigating to view");
                    // HERE IS WHERE THE TROUBLE LIES! THIS DOESNT WORK
                    FacesUtils.setNextViewNavigation(outcome.getViewId());
                }
            } catch (final FrameworkException fe) {
                LOGGER.debug("Exception caught {}", fe);
                caseNotFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

outcome is an enumeration containing amongst other things the view I need to navigate to, and the application state (another enumeration). If applicationState is quote, I want to silently navigate. For all other applicationStates I want to challenge the user to verify them.

My facesUtils method is:

```
public static void setNextViewNavigation(final String p_lastAccessedViewId) {
    if (p_lastAccessedViewId != null) {
        getCurrentViewRoot().setViewId(p_lastAccessedViewId);
    }
}
```

I've also tried calling this method

```
public static void navigateToOutcome(final String p_outcome) {
    final FacesContext context = getFacesContext();
    final NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, p_outcome);
}
```

Despite my efforts, I'm seeing the landing page wheras I want to silently navigate to the saved page

Basically I want to abort the current lifecycle and reset the viewroot to the saved view. (note I am not saving the component tree itself, just my business objects)

One more piece of information, this is jsf1.2, but with facelets. I cannot use any jsf2 specific functionality, nor can I use any third party JSF extenstions.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by using a ui:include tag with the src attribute being a jsf method that determines the name of the page to navigate to.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what we ended up doing, it's a bit clunky but does work.